# Page to redirect dependent on multiple 'select' choices

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to make a page redirect to the relevant page dependent on two `select` choices. I'm unsure whether this would be best done with Javascript or PHP as I want to be able to change the pages easily- which makes me think some kind of PHP form handler would be best.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0xy3y1uv/1/)

Any examples of how this could work would be greatly appreciated. I've made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0xy3y1uv/1/) to help. If I haven't been specific enough, I'm trying to get the page redirected to a certain page if someone selects "Engineering" and then "New South Wales", and somewhere else if they select "Health" and then "New South Wales" etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can do this in php with `if`/`else` -> `if($_POST['specialist'] == "Engineering" && $_POST['state'] == "New South Wales"){ $redirect = 'page1.php';} else if ($_POST['specialist'] == "Health" && $_POST['state'] == "New South Wales"){ $redirect = 'page2.php';} else if ...`

Comment: What is you redirect links like? If there is a pattern that it follows (e.g. for "Engineering" and then "New South Wales" redirect to www.example.com/engg/newsouthwales and for "Health" and then "Queensland" www.example.com/health/queensland etc) you can do it more efficiently. and do you plan to use php or it will be just javascript.

Comment: @karmendra Unfortunately I'm unsure of what the URLs will be at this stage as we are still playing with site structure so they probably will have to be done less efficiently. I also would prefer to use PHP so I can just set the form action to the PHP file and it will redirect from there. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Sean Thanks Sean, I'll have a play with that. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Tried `<?php
  if ($_POST['specialist'] == "engineering" && $_POST['state'] == "act"){ $redirect = 'act.php';}
else if ($_POST['specialist'] == "engineering" && $_POST['state'] == "nsw"){ $redirect = 'nsw.php';}
else if ($_POST['specialist'] == "engineering" && $_POST['state'] == "nt"){ $redirect = 'nt.php';} ...` But still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit more cleaner solution would be

```
<?php
if ($_POST['specialist'] == "engineering" && isset($_POST['state'])){
    switch($_POST['state']){
        case "act":
            header("Location: act.php");
        break;
        case "nsw":
            header("Location: nsw.php");
        break;
        case "nt":
            header("Location: nt.php");
        break;
        default:
            // Redirect to a default page if not matched or some other message
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

This way you don't have to check for engineer each time. You can make multiple of these for different professions. Also it's good practice to use an `exit();` or `break;` after a redirect, which is implemented in this case.

You could make it even faster by taking the `$_POST` variable and using it directly, though this is prone to abuse from other people so make sure you check the available values.

```
<?php

$engineering_states = array('act', 'nsw', 'nt', 'qld', 'sa', 'tas', 'vic', 'wa');

if($_POST['specialist'] == "engineering"){
    if(in_array($_POST['state'], $engineering_states)){
        header("Location: $_POST['state'].php");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! So would you just use `else if` to add "health" below, for example?

Comment: having many if else if will become very unmanageable and unreadable as the code grows, in those situations you prefer switch case. and as per the code above a else if for health will suit.

Comment: Or just another `if` block. Since it will skip the block if it's not engineering. Use `if-else` only when you need either of the code blocks to be executed. Else it's just more code for the same actions :)

Comment: @verrucktfuchs I added an alternative and shorter version see if you like this one.

Comment: @TomKriek Thank you! That makes perfect sense. Really appreciate all your help and time with this.

Comment: @verrucktfuchs That's why this site exists! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, @Sean's comment provided most of it, I just adjusted the code slightly. Working PHP:

`<?php
     if ($_POST['specialist'] == "engineering" && $_POST['state'] == "act"){ header("Location: act.php");}
else if ($_POST['specialist'] == "engineering" && $_POST['state'] == "nsw"){ header("Location: nsw.php");}
else if ($_POST['specialist'] == "engineering" && $_POST['state'] == "nt"){ header("Location: nt.php");} ...` etc

Answer (score 0):

My way to do this would be to create an array (which can also be replaced by a database as well in future easily).

```
<?php
$a = Array(
    "engineering" => Array( "act"=>"enggact.php",
                            "nsw"=>"enggnsw.php",
                            "nt"=>"enggnt.php"
                          ),
    "health" => Array(  "act"=>"heltact.php",
                            "nsw"=>"heltnsw.php",
                            "nt"=>"heltnt.php"
                          ),
    "information-technology" => Array(  "act"=>"itact.php",
                            "nsw"=>"itnsw.php",
                            "nt"=>"itnt.php"
                          )
);
if(isset($a[$_POST['specialist']][$_POST['state']])) {
    header("Location:".$a[$_POST['specialist']][$_POST['state']]);
}
?>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks very much @karmendra! This is also a great solution, the reason I went with the other was only because it will probably be easier for me to change. If I have any issues will try this. Thanks again.

Comment: Not a problem, you can choose the way you are comfortable with. But I felt this code is easy to scale, read and maintain this i.e. if you want to add one more link you just need to add an element in the array. Think when you have to change/add one entry how many lines of code you need to add modify. More code you add/change more chances of adding a bug, my philosophy.

Comment: Very true! Thanks- hopefully we'll know the site structure soon and can simplify